# Debugging public key authentication with paramiko

Tags: public-key-encryption, paramiko, public-key

Is there any way to confirm which file (and what contents) paramiko is sending out when attempting to authenticate using public key authentication?

Up until now the authentication has worked. It's not working all of a sudden and I want to confirm that the correct public key is being sent to the server.

Also, given a private key file, how does paramiko determine the public key to send to the server? Is this pulled from a file somewhere on the server, or is it calculated from the private key?